# Unable to download jmeter plugin: Json Path Extractor

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

[image]

I am unable to download the apache jmeter, Json Path Extractor, the loader keeping loading.

url: https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to install a JMeter plugin is using [Plugin Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Download the jar and put it in `\lib\ext` folder and Restart `JMeter`

Then go to `Options -> Plugin Manager` where you can chose the pluign you want to install directly from `JMeter GUI` itself.

What was the issue related to downloading? `Jar file` is not shown?

Comment: Yep, the issue is with downloading, I have the plugin manager installed

Comment: The second method worked for me: Options -> Plugin Manager > apply changes & restart @Naveen Thank you.