# Getting exception while using jp@gc Graphs Generator

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am new to `Jmeter` and getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.SynthesisReportGui` when using `jp@gc Graph generator plugin` in Jmeter v 3.0. Please help.

I am trying to run Jmeter in **GUI** mode.[Jmeter configuration Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcpgJ.png)

I have placed following jars in `lib`:

```
jmeter-plugins-graphs-ggl-2.0.jar
cmdrunner-2.0.jar
jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.3.jar
```

and following in `ext` folder:

```
jmeter-plugins-graphs-ggl-2.0.jar
jmeter-plugins-manager-0.10.jar
cmdrunner-2.0.jar
jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.3.jar
jmeter-plugins-cmd-2.1.jar
```

Following is the log:

```
2017/02/13 18:31:09 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2017/02/13 18:31:09 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: CIC_Perf_Wall 1-2 
2017/02/13 18:31:09 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: CIC_Perf_Wall 1-1 
2017/02/13 18:31:09 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: CIC_Perf_Wall 1-5 
2017/02/13 18:31:09 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: CIC_Perf_Wall 1-3 
2017/02/13 18:31:09 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: CIC_Perf_Wall 1-4 
2017/02/13 18:31:18 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: CIC_Perf_Wall 1-3 
2017/02/13 18:31:18 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: CIC_Perf_Wall 1-3 
2017/02/13 18:31:18 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: CIC_Perf_Wall 1-1 
2017/02/13 18:31:18 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: CIC_Perf_Wall 1-1 
2017/02/13 18:31:18 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: CIC_Perf_Wall 1-4 
2017/02/13 18:31:18 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: CIC_Perf_Wall 1-4 
2017/02/13 18:31:18 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: CIC_Perf_Wall 1-2 
2017/02/13 18:31:18 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: CIC_Perf_Wall 1-2 
2017/02/13 18:31:18 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: CIC_Perf_Wall 1-5 
2017/02/13 18:31:18 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: CIC_Perf_Wall 1-5 
2017/02/13 18:31:18 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2017/02/13 18:31:18 INFO  - jmeter.config.KeystoreConfig: Destroying Keystore 
2017/02/13 18:31:18 INFO  - kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker: Using JMeterPluginsCMD v. N/A 
2017/02/13 18:31:18 WARN  - kg.apc.jmeter.JMeterPluginsUtils: JMeter env exists. No one should see this normally. 
2017/02/13 18:31:18 WARN  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Error encountered during shutdown of kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener@215ff3c0 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.SynthesisReportGui
    at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.getGUIObject(PluginsCMDWorker.java:237)
    at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.getGUIObject(PluginsCMDWorker.java:234)
    at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.setPluginType(PluginsCMDWorker.java:73)
    at kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener.testEnded(GraphsGeneratorListener.java:221)
    at kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener.testEnded(GraphsGeneratorListener.java:137)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfEnd(StandardJMeterEngine.java:215)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:436)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.SynthesisReportGui


2017/02/13 18:31:18 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```

[Jmeter configuration Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcpgJ.png)

Comment: Best way to install JMeter Plugins is using `Plugin Manager`. More details here http://stackoverflow.com/a/42176372/2575259. try it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error you're getting is about missing [Synthesis Report plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SynthesisReport/), you need to:

- download it from https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-synthesis
- drop to `lib/ext` folder of your JMeter installation
- restart JMeter to pick up the plugin

Another (better) way of installing the plugins and keeping them up-to-date is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)