# Cannot install JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin

Tags: java, json, jmeter, extractor

I cannot install JSON Path Extractor Plugin from Plugin manager nor manually.

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176117/unable-to-download-jmeter-plugin-json-path-extractor) but I cannot find the plugin by name using plugin manager and the same here https://jmeter-plugins.org/.

I am using jmeter 3.3.

How can I achieve it or is there an alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look for `JSON Plugins` in the [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image: JMeter JSON Plugins]

However be aware that it is "deprecated" and may be removed in future releases, it is recommended to switch to the following test elements instead:

- [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)
- [JSON Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion)

Both are available out-of-the-box in [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4)